# DNS caching "-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=30" in glassfish v3?

Tags: domain-name-system, java, glassfish

Excuse my basic question, but i am a software engineer and not very experienced with server admin.

I am using [reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/) in my **j2ee** application, and on google's site they say that the reCAPTCHA plugin for java requires modifying DNS caching (put it 30 seconds). 
This is mentioned in the following [Link](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java) (at the bottom of the page **"-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=30"**)

How can i set it up in glassfish v3?

Comment: What OS are you running on, and how is Glassfish being started?

Comment: @ShaneMadden   its a windows machin : right now am testing on localhost windows 7, and glassfish is being started from netbeans ide. But i will be moving to a production server soon (windows also) and i will need to set it there again. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the JVM settings for your domain doing the following:

1. open glassfish admin console (by default it would be on port
   4848)
2. go to Configuration -> JVM Settings
3. choose JVM Options tab
4. add your JVM option
5. stop and start glassfish domain

You could also use asadmin on the commandline, something like:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=30
```

Comment: thx a lot for your help, much appreciated! I got a notice that i cannot award the bounty before 5 hours, so will do it at that time.Have a good one:)